# Flutter project in iOS emulator takes forever to run, but its worked on Android emulator

Tags: ios, flutter, android-emulator

I'm working on a Flutter project, and when I run the project with the Andriod emulator it works fine, but when I try the iOS emulator it takes forever (or maybe never) to run and the debug console shows "Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 11 in debug mode.."

I tried the iOS emulator with another project and its works without any problems.

Answer (score 1):

As akdev answered that steps are necessary but if you added any plugin to your  flutter app then also go to iOS folder using  `cd ios` and use  `pod install` hope this works.

Answer (score 0):

Try `flutter clean` and `flutter build ios` in android studio before opening project in xcode. After successful build open the project in XCode and run in emulator.